# WooCommerce adding checkout form template

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am new on Wordpress and I want to add new payment method on wooCommerce so I added new payment method to checkout options on admin side.

Here is my all addition under `woocommerce/wp-content/plugins/myplugin`:

http://paste.ubuntu.com/23159841/

On the client side, I created new template for displaying credit card form. I want to see this form on new page after "checkout now" button clicked.

How can I integrate my template with WooCommerce? I didn't find any example like that.

Comment: We need an MCVE of what you have so far: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 0):

When you click "Proceed To Checkout" button in next page you automatically got credit card payment option (If you enable it). You don't need to create any extra page.